# Load scss variables at runtime before nuxt.config.js 'css' is loaded

Tags: nuxt.js

I want to override some scss-variables on a css framework at runtime based on domain. In other word, i want to load my {domain}.varaibles.scss before the framework is loaded.

Now the framework is loaded in nuxt.config "css" property:

```
css: [
   'bulma'
],
```

To override $primary it needs to be loaded before bulma.

Is there any way i can accomplish this?

Comment: maybe you can consider to use css variables instead of scss varibles